# how to get the count of all the elements in the field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have one table:

```
id | name |
-----------
1  | AAA  |
2  | BBB  |
3  | AAA  |
4  | DDD  |
5  | BBB  |
6  | CCC  |
7  | AAA  |
8  | BBB  |
9  | DDD  |
```

I want to count the that how many times `AAA` ,`BBB` and so on are there.
By using count(*) i am getting the hole count not for single element.
I want the count of all the elements.
like this:

```
Name | Count
------------
AAA  | 3
BBB  | 3
CCC  | 1
DDD  | 2
```

Not in new table i want it as output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` aggregate function to get the total number of records for each `NAME`.

```
SELECT  name, COUNT(*) totalCOUNT
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a597/2)

Comment: what if i want to get only the elements which have count more then 2.?

Comment: add `HAVING` clause, example, `HAVING COUNT(*) > 2` see here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a597/3

Answer (score 0):

```
Select name,Count(*) as 'total'
from yourTableName
GroupBy
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way to count rows with what you want to match:

sql> select count(*) as count from table_name where name like 'AAA';

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name AS Name,
       count(name) AS Count
FROM Table
GROUP BY name ASC;
```